# Probability (X >Y) when X and Y have the same distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is a problem from HW4 Joe Blitzstein's Harvard Stat 110 course.

Let X be a random day of the week, coded so that Monday is 1, Tuesday is 2, etc. (so X takes values 1, 2, . . . , 7, with equal probabilities). Let Y be the next day after X (again represented as an integer between 1 and 7). Do X and Y have the same distribution? What is P (X < Y )?

My solution:

$$
P( X < Y) = P(X<Y|Y = 1)P(Y=1) + P(X<Y|Y=2)P(Y=2) +...+ P(X<Y|Y=7)P(Y=7)
= {1\over7}[{0\over7} + {1\over7} + {2\over7}+ {3\over7} +{4\over7} +{5\over7} +{6\over7}]
={21\over49} = {3\over7}
$$

Joe's solution:
$$
P(X < Y) = P(X \neq 7 ) = {6\over7}
$$
Can someone point out where my logic went wrong?

Comment: "Let Y be the next day after X" - i.e. Y = X + 1 (mod 7). The only way that X + 1 > Y is if X = 7.

Basically, you're reasoning isn't wrong, it's just that you misread the question. I do this *all the time*.

Comment: X and Y have the same distribution, but that doesn't mean that they're _independent_.  Your solution is predicated on the notion that they're independent, specifically in the step where you transition from e.g. $P(X\lt Y|Y=4)$ to $P(X\lt 4)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your $${1\over7}\left[{0\over7} + {1\over7} + {2\over7}+ {3\over7} +{4\over7} +{5\over7} +{6\over7}\right]$$ should have been $${1\over7}\left[{0+1+1+1+1+1+1}\right]$$ since $X$ counts as the day immediately before $Y$, except on Sunday/Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you say $P(X < Y) + P(X = Y) + P( X > Y) = 1$ ?

Then since $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.  Then $P(X > Y) = P(X < Y)$.

It remains to compute how often $X = Y$.  In many cases this occurs with probability zero.

$$ P(X> Y) = 1 - \frac{1}{2} P(X=Y) = 1 - \frac{1}{2\cdot 7}$$

---

In fact you can say $P(X < Y) + P(X = Y) + P( X > Y) = 1$ but you can't say the second one: $$\boxed{P(X > Y) \neq P(X < Y)}$$

This is because if we know $X$ we can determine $Y$ and vice versa.  Your conditional probabilities are wrong:

$$ P(X < Y | Y=1) = P( X < 1 | X = 7) = 0$$