# Are two random variable $X, Y$ independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

**Problem :**

Let $X$ be a random day of the week, coded so that Monday is 1, Tuesday is 2, etc. (so $X$ takes values 1, 2, . . . , 7, with equal probabilities). Let $Y$ be the next day after $X$ (again represented as an integer between 1 and 7).

Are $X, Y$ independent? or not?

In fact, similar problem is here in MSE : [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999988/probability-x-y-when-x-and-y-have-the-same-distribution)

---

**My Attempt**

(I have additional question which determine independence. Check above question too.)

I find that $X, Y$ have same PMF because both $X$ and $Y$ takes $1, 2, \cdots 7$ with equal probabilities.

And since $Y$ denotes next day of $X$,

$$P(X<Y)=P(X\neq 7) = 1-P(X=7) = \frac{6}{7}$$

Now, I should determine the independence of $X$ and $Y$.

I learned that if two random variable $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if

$$p(x,y)=p(x)\cdot p(y)$$

where $p(x, y)$ is joint PMF of $X$ and $Y$ and $p(x), p(y)$ denote marginal PMF of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

So, I need to know joint PMF of $X$ and $Y$ but how can I find it?

or is there another way to determine independence of $X$ and $Y$ with using facts that $X, Y$ have same PMF and $P(X<Y)=\frac{6}{7}$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If $Y$ was independent, $P(X<Y)=\frac37$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$p(x,y)=p(x)\cdot p(y)$$

You need to show this equation hold for all $x, y$ if and only if you want to prove $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

However, if you want to show they are NOT independent, you only need to find one counter-example, i.e. $x=x_1, y=y_2$, such that

$$p(x_1,y_2)\neq p(x_1)\cdot p(y_2)$$

For this problem, you can set for example, $x=3, y=1$, then $p(3,1)=0$, but RHS is not zero, hence they are not independent.

Comment: Even if there is no specific expression of joint PMF $p(x, y)$, there is no probability that 'next day of wednesday is monday' so $p(3, 1)=0$? Did I understand your intent correctly?

Comment: Yes, your understand is correct, the probability is $0$. Since you want to disprove it, you only need one counter-example is enough. @bFur4list